# What verb to use with "shortcoming"?

Tags: word-usage, verbs

You are saying:

> As can be seen, the proposed algorithm may fail to give the correct answer. In order to `improve this shortcoming`, we suggest the following modifications.

What is the right word to use with "shortcoming" in this situation? I used `improve` but I do not know if this is the correct verb.

Comment: I agree that "improve" isn't quite right; it would imply that you're trying to make the shortcoming more effective, which would make the bearer of the shortcoming worse off. :-)

Comment: Why mention *shortcoming*? Just say "... In order to rectify this, we suggest the following modifications."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to `correct this shortcoming`, we suggest the following modifications.

Comment: The problem I might have with this, is that the shortcoming may still be there.. often time shortcomings are inherent to something and you need away to "get around" the problem.

Comment: "correct for" this shortcoming would work great though

Answer (score 2):

In addition to @Paul Brinkley's suggestion of *correct*, you could use the word [***mitigate***](http://thefreedictionary.com/mitigate), which implies improving a shortcoming but not necessarily completely correcting it.

Answer (score 1):

***Overcome*** *this shortcoming*

I'm most familiar with a sentence like "In order to overcome this shortcoming, we put non slip tape on the floor".

> ***overcome*** [oxford dicitonaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/overcome)
>   VERB
>
> [WITH OBJECT]
>
> 1Succeed in dealing with (a problem or difficulty):
>   ‘he overcame his pain for a time’
>
> 1.1 Defeat (an opponent):
>   ‘an experienced England side overcame the determined home team’
>
> 1.2 (of a feeling or emotion) overpower or overwhelm:
>   ‘she was obviously overcome with excitement’

Comment: But that sounds horrible.

Comment: @TonyK ok lol I guess two 'comings" is one too much. Overcome a problem, "Get around" this shortcoming. Correct is fine too